# Ionic 4 Http request failure in iOS

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic4

I'm facing a strange issue on only iOS when making Http request. On android, and in browser everything works well, but when I'm on iOS after few requests, I'm facing failure response for (unknown url) 0 unknown error, it's really completely random. Sometimes I can make so many requests I think it's okay but after few minutes using my application I fall in the same issue, can difficultly reproduce. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `YES` in your info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

[image]

Comment: I already had this in my config.xml but still continue having the same problem.

Comment: @MahamadouDOUMBIA check your ios project info.plist file it's added or not